# Matrix structure organizational design in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a matrix structure organizational diagram with tikz?

It should be something like this. Not quite the same, just something to sketch that the boxes are crossing one another in two dimensions (i.e. it doesn't have to be the same line types, sizes, etc.).

[image]

I have already tried myself with just positioning the nodes, but I'm afraid it wont work - and if it does, it will probably be quite messy.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{box} = [draw=black,fill=none]

\node[box] (a) {Top management};

\node[box,below=1cm of a] (b) {Section leader};
\node[box,right=1cm of b] (c) {Section leader};
\node[box,left=1cm of b] (d) {Section leader};

\node[box,below=1cm of b] (e) {};
\node[box,below=1cm of c] (f) {};
\node[box,below=1cm of d] (g) {};

\node[box,left=1cm of g] (h) {Section leader};
\node[box,below=1cm of h] (i) {Section leader};
\node[box,below=1cm of i] (j) {Section leader};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? I partly follow your code, mostly your sketch ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,positioning,shadows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm,
    start chain = 1 going right,
    start chain = 2 going below,
box/.style = {draw=black, align=left, on chain=1}
                        ]
\node[box] (b) {Section leader 1};
\node[box] (c) {Section leader 2};
\node[box] (d) {Section leader 3};
    \node[box,above=8mm of c] (a) {Top management};
%
    \begin{scope}[box/.append style={on chain=2}]
\node[box,below left=of b] (h) {Section\\ leader 4};
\node[box] (i) {Section\\ leader 5};
\node[box] (j) {Section\\ leader 6};
    \end{scope}
% arrows
\draw   (a) -- (c)  (b.north) -- + (0,4mm) -| (d);
\draw[draw=gray,line width=1mm, -{Triangle[fill=gray,length=2mm]}]
    (b) edge (j.south -| b) (c) edge (j.south -| c) (d) edge (j.south -| d)
    (h) edge (d.east |- h)  (i) edge (d.east |- i)  (j) edge (d.east |- j);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Just perfect; however, if the box with "Section leader 6" doesn't use 2 lines, the arrows heading from north to south is not long enough. What can I do to make it a bit longer?

Comment: I draw arrows according to provided sketch :-) otherwise, I don't understand your comment. The vertical arrows are aligned with south border of node "6". It you like that they protrude this border, you need to change their coordinates accordingly. For example \coordinate[below=of j.south] (k); and then replace j.south` in (j.south -| b) ... by (k -| b) ...